# QGIS Zonal Stats Plugin - Python Console - compute one specific statistic

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics

I think this is more of a syntax problem that I have here. But I am absolutely not able to figure it out.
On a different Linux machine I got the following working:

```
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath, 'pre-', 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean())
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

to just calculate the mean and then append it to the .dbf file of the shapefile.
The error I get is `TypeError: 'Statistic' object is not callable`.
I see whats the problem, but even after studying the [API](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsZonalStatistics.html#details) I couldn't figure it out.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [QgsZonalStatistics.Mean](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsZonalStatistics.html) it's part of an enumeration - it's actually the integer 4. You're calling it as if it's a function.

Try removing the brackets:-

```
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath, 'pre-', 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

Note that these values are done as powers of two; to get a combination of several stats, you can sum them (or use a binary or)

e.g. to get maximum, minimum and mean use the `python bitwise or` (the 'pipe' character)

```
QgsZonalStatistics.Mean | QgsZonalStatistics.Max | QgsZonalStatistics.Min
```

so...

```
zoneStat = QgsZonalStatistics (polygonLayer, rasterFilePath, 'pre-', 1, QgsZonalStatistics.Mean | QgsZonalStatistics.Max | QgsZonalStatistics.Min)
zoneStat.calculateStatistics(None)
```

Comment: how would I add a combination of several of them to the QgsZonalStatistics() function as numbers? I mean from a syntax point of view. Thanks for this great hint by the way!

Comment: no problems - added an example to the answer.